# Issue in pragmatically create orders in magento 2

Tags: orders, custom, magento2.2.2, programmatically

I want to create orders pragmatically by getting the data from xml.
Reading data from xml part is done.
when creating order steps i am getting this error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$quote' (T_VARIABLE) in

Below is my code lines

```
<?php
namespace Eight25media\MpowerSync\Controller\Adminhtml\mpowersync;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

class Testorderimport extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
......some code here.....
protected $quote;
protected $quoteManagement;
......some code here.....
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
......some code here.....
\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote,
\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
......some code here.....
) { 
parent::__construct($context);
......some code here.....
$this->quote = $quote;
$this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
......some code here.....
}

public function execute(){
......some code here.....
$websiteId  = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
$customer = $this->customer;
if ($websiteId) {
 $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
}
$customer->loadByEmail($email);
$customer_id = $customer->getId();
if(!$customer->getId()){
//create customer 
}

$store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
$quote = $this->quote->create();
$quote->setStore($store);

$customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customer_id);
$quote->setCurrency($order_currency_code);
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);
......some code here.....
```

I am getting this error `$quote->assignCustomer($customer)` here in this line.

May be some one faced the same issue you before, any help would be great for me to short it out or else suggest me a tutorial.

I tried [Magecamp](https://magecomp.com/blog/create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2/), [mageplaza](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-order-programmatically.html),[webkul](https://webkul.com/blog/create-quote-and-order-programmatically-in-magento2/) tutorials.

Comment: have you used the cartManagementInterface and cartRepositoryInterface in order to load quote that define in webkul tutorial? Also please write the complete error in question

Comment: Hi @Mujahidh, Can you please remove comma behind this line \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,

Comment: @MuhammadHasham no i dint try

Comment: @Ravi There were some other lines coming after that

Comment: I thought it was the last line.

Comment: Update with full code

Comment: @Mujahidh then try it is working code, I also used it